# recursive match with boost regex library

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am new to boost and trying to construct a vector, (it would be vector of objects holding direction(Y/NO) & count) from the fields in string below, but this string length would be arbitrary, can someone suggest how do I    match the exact string with `boost::regex` & store it ?

```
std::string str = "Y-10,NO-3,NO-4,Y-100"
```

EDIT:
This is what I have done, but not sure if this is optimal ?

```
boost::regex expr{"((Y|NO)-\\d+)"};
boost::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> it{pattern.begin(), pattern.end(), expr, 1};
boost::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> end;
while (it != end) {
   std::string pat = *it;
   boost::regex sub_expr {"(Y|NO)-(\\d+)"};
   boost::smatch match;
   if (boost::regex_search(pat, match, sub_expr)) {
      ...
      ...     
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use Spirit here:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c68cb56c32b0dca)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

enum class YNO { NO, Y };

struct YNoToken : qi::symbols<char, YNO> {
    YNoToken() { add("Y", YNO::Y)("NO", YNO::NO); }
} static YNo;

int main() {
    std::string const str = "Y-10,NO-3,NO-4,Y-100";
    auto f = str.begin(), l = str.end();

    std::vector<std::pair<YNO, int> > v;

    bool ok = qi::parse(f, l, (YNo >> '-' >> qi::int_) % ',', v);
    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parse success: \n";
        for (auto pair : v)
            std::cout << (pair.first==YNO::Y? "Y":"NO") << "\t" << pair.second << "\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Parse success: 
Y   10
NO  3
NO  4
Y   100
```

You can achieve a similar result with regex, but you'd be left doing manual work for checking and converting the submatches.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I like this approach, although haven't used these  libraries before